# Table rendering issue in Firefox with border-collapse:collapse

Tags: html, firefox, html-table

Following HTML renders incorrectly with latest Firefox. IE and Chrome are ok but Firefox displays white vertical line inside the table cell.

Example rendered with Firefox 21 can be found here:

http://tinypic.com/r/2w2qvb6/5

[image: Firefox]

Is this a bug in Firefox or am I missing something?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
table{
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 0px;
}

div{
    background:blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Removing `border-collapse: collapse;` removes the vertical white line. But I really want to collapse the table borders.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FeuBx/

Update: The problem appears only with 100% browser zoom level (Ctrl + 0).

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue on Chrome or Firefox (21.0).

Comment: Probably it's worth specifying. JSfiddle above produce error for me on: Firefox 20.0.1 Win32 and Firefox 21.0 Win32 with 100% browser zoom level.

Comment: Browser window size, div position on screen and browser zoom - all of that matters. I have reported FF bug for that (Bug 883654).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as is if you set an HTML5 DOCTYPE at the top of your page as in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 0px;
}

div{
    background:blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The page where I have encountered this problem already does have the HTML5 doctype. JSfiddle above also have html 5 doctype set. The problem seem to be very unstable. It actually depends on browser zoom level. It is only visible in 100% and disappears if you change it to any direction.

Comment: That is strange, if you put the code I wrote into an html file and load it up in firefox 21 it looks correct for me, but for some reason on the fiddle it is not working properly even though it has a html5 doctype. Also, if I remove the html5 doctype it shows incorrectly -- the way it shows up in the fiddle.

Comment: If you adjust the width of the iframe on the fiddle the border disappears and it renders correctly. I wonder if there is an issue with javascript resizing the iframe in the fiddle that is causing the issue.

Comment: Good spot! The issue seems to be sensitive to position of the element. As JSfiddle saves panes layout the issue is disappearing once default layout is adjusted. Only clearing jsfiddle settings reverts it back. With resized panes I got even FF to hide left cell border with 90% zoom.